# How to get TextFieldStyle cursor in a skin?

Tags: java, libgdx

So I have a skin, and the JSON part for the TextFieldStyle looks like so:

```
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField$TextFieldStyle: {
    default: {
      font: font
      fontColor: black
      background: textfield
      cursor: black
      selection: pale-blue
    }
  }
```

With my script, I want to get the cursor. I've already tried `skin.getDrawable("cursor")`, `skin.getDrawable("default-cursor")`, and `skin.getDrawable("textfieldstyle-default-cursor")`, which don't work. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
skin.get("default", TextFieldStyle.class).cursor
```

where "default" is the actual name of your text field style.